# How to batch upload blobs to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to upload a set of files to Azure Storage in a batch.
[I was looking into this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-batch) but Is there a good SDK for doing the same?

Also I've found [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs.Batch/). Seems like this only allows deleting blobs in batch. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Looking for a solution too.  The only thing I've seen is uploading in parallel which is not a batch

Answer (score 0):

Did you explore [**`Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement`**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/) This is an extended version of [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) which allows you to upload in parralel.